# Vue Router: how to cast params as integers instead of strings?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When I enter a URL using the browser field, the params are cast as strings, rather than an integer, e.g. `/user/1` returns `{id: "1"}`. However, when when using `this.$route.push({})`, the params are, correctly, cast as integers `{id: 1}`.

Is this behavior intended? If not, how do I fix it?

Comment: well, urls are strings, and js values are whatever value type you use; are you sure `this.$route.push` will not convert any and all params to str anyway - since it mimics a navigation with an url

Comment: `push()` does *not* convert any type. I have tested using both an integer and a string.

Using `this.$router.push({name:'user', params: { id: 1 }});` will result in `$route.params.id = 1` and using `this.$router.push({name:'user', params: { id: "1" }});` will result in `$route.params.id = "1"`.

Comment: @birdspider - yes but some other frameworks are able to handle this and you're able to specify a param type with little extra syntax

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You have to handle casting any params values yourself. In the route object define a props function. Here is an example:

```
{
  path: '/user/:userId',
  component: UserProfile,
  props: (route) => {
    /**
     * This would preserve the other route.params object properties overriding only 
     * `userId` in case it exists with its integer equivalent, or otherwise with 
     * undefined.
     */
    return { ...route.params, ...{ userId: Number.parseInt(route.params.userId, 10) || undefined }
  }
}
```

[Link](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#Function-mode) to vue router docs this is under Function mode

Comment: If you have many routes, this is unfortunately repetitive and excessive. They should implement some syntactic sugar like `/user/:userId<int>` or something similar to support quick type definition.

Comment: Write own fxn. to do this like [shown here.](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/38e6ccd7757bfdf333bb32a1e496e4359b8ec00f/examples/route-props/app.js#L7)

Comment: `props: ({params}) => ({userId: Number.parseInt(params.userId, 10) || 0})`

Comment: @CodeFinity: thx, works like a charm and is cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

I'm probably late to the party, but this is my take on this. I wrote a function that returns a function that casts route params values to the props with same name with the given type.

```js
function paramsToPropsCaster(mapping) {
  return function(route) {
    let nameType = Object.entries(mapping);  // [[param1, Number], [param2, String]]
    let nameRouteParam = nameType.map(([name, fn]) => [name, fn(route.params[name])]);  // [[param1, 1], [param2, "hello"]]
    let props = Object.fromEntries(nameRouteParam);  // {param1: 1, param2: "hello"}
    return props;
  }
}
```

And then, in your route definition:

```js
{
      path: '/projects/:param1/editor/:param2', 
      component: ProjectEditor,
      name: 'project-editor',
      props: paramsToPropsCaster({'param1': Number, 'param2': String}),
}
```

This is just a hint on what you can do to solve the problem asked here, don't use this verbatim!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array in props to support both types

```
props: { 
    type:[Number,String],
    required:true
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't actually cast the value per the OP's question, it just accepts either type.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Vue Router doesn't provide a shortcut for this, so I've come up with my own.  The `castParams` function below generates a props function that has the specified type casting built in.  I've added casting for integers and booleans but you can easily extend this for whatever other types you want to cast to.

```
// casts should be an object where the keys are params that might appear in the route, and the values specify how to cast the parameters
const castParams = (casts) => {
    return (route) => {
        const props = {};
        for (var key in route.params) {
            const rawValue = route.params[key];
            const cast = casts[key];
            if (rawValue == null) {
                // Don't attempt to cast null or undefined values
                props[key] = rawValue;
            } else if (cast == null) {
                // No cast specified for this parameter
                props[key] = rawValue;
            } else if (cast == 'integer') {
                // Try to cast this parameter as an integer
                const castValue = Number.parseInt(rawValue, 10);
                props[key] = isNaN(castValue) ? rawValue : castValue;
            } else if (cast == 'boolean') {
                // Try to cast this parameter as a boolean
                if (rawValue === 'true' || rawValue === '1') {
                    props[key] = true;
                } else if (rawValue === 'false' || rawValue === '0') {
                    props[key] = false;
                } else {
                    props[key] = rawValue;
                }
            } else if (typeof(cast) == 'function') {
                // Use the supplied function to cast this param
                props[key] = cast(rawValue);
            } else {
                console.log("Unexpected route param cast", cast);
                props[key] = rawValue;
            }
        }
        return props;
    };
};
```

Then you can use it in your route definitions, eg:

```
{
    path: '/contact/:contactId',
    component: 'contact-details-page',
    props: castParams({contactId: 'integer'}),
},
```

Comment: Something like this must be built-in. Thank you! Design is great. Maybe exact code in casters (integer) is not strict enough.

Answer (score 0):

I do prefer Rodener Dajes answer, and handle type casting and validation within the component instead of in the route definition:

```
props: {
        id: {
            type: [Number, String],
            default: 0
        },
    },
```

The reason is that it will allow me to define the route much simpler and readable:

```
{
path: '/job/:id',
name: 'Job',
component: InvoiceJobDetail,
props: true
}
```

Comment: But if your component uses the proper equality checks (=== or !==), your toasted

Answer (score 0):

Many of these solutions seem unnecessary complex to me.

Here's what I did in my project - note that route params ending in `ID` or the param `id` itself, are automatically converted to `Number`, so in my case I just had to set `props: typedProps(),` in nearly all of my routes.

```js
/**
 * Casts props into proper data types.
 * Props ending in 'ID' and the prop 'id' are cast to Number automatically.
 * To cast other props or override the defaults, pass a mapping like this:
 * @example
 * // Truthy values like 'true', 'yes', 'on' and '1' are converted to Boolean(true)
 * {
 *  path: '/:isNice/:age/:hatSize',
 *  name: 'foo route',
 *  props: typedProps({ isNice: Boolean, age: Number, hatSize: Number}),
 * },
 * @param {Object} mapping
 * @returns
 */
const typedProps = (mapping) => {
  if (!mapping) {
    mapping = {}
  }
  
  return (route) => {
    let props = {}
    for (let [prop, value] of Object.entries(route.params)) {
      if (prop in mapping) {
        if (mapping[prop] === Boolean) {
          value = ['true', '1', 'yes', 'on'].includes(value.toLowerCase())
        } else {
          value = mapping[prop](value)
        }
      } else if (prop === 'id' || prop.endsWith('ID')) {
        value = Number(value)
      }
      
      props[prop] = value
    }

    return props
  }
}
```

This could use some error handling in case a type coercion fails, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the excellent answer from @pongi: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63897213 I came up with a new package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-router-parse-props. It's written in typescript and has types. Please let me know, what you think.

```
npm i vue-router-parse-props
```

```js
// src/router/index.ts
import propsParser from 'vue-router-parse-props'
import { parse } from 'date-fns'

const router = new Router({
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  mode: useHistory ? "history" : "hash",
  routes: [
    {
      path: ':day/:userId',
      name: 'UserProfile',
      component: () => import('@/components/UserProfile.vue'),
      props: paramsToPropsCaster({ 
        userId: Number,
        day: (val: string): Date => parse(val, 'yyyy-MM-dd', new Date()),
        searchId: {
          type: id,
          routeKey: "query.q"
        }
      })
    }
  ]
});
```