# I encounterd this error "Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "categoryId". Expected Number with value 13, got String with value "13""

Tags: vue.js

When I changed the props data type from String to Number, I get the error.
Although I checked again and again for strange parts, I couldn't find it.
I don't know why It worked well with String type.

In the code below,
CategoryHome is the parent Component of CategoryShow.

Could you tell me Where are mistakes in my code?

The blow image is screen design.

[image]

```
// CategoryShow.vue
<script setup>
import axios from "axios";
import { ref, watch} from "vue"

import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const route = useRoute()

const router = useRouter()

const props = defineProps({
  categoryId: {
    //type: String,
     type: Number
  }
})

const categories = ref([])

const singleCategory = ref({})

const recipes = ref([])


const getCategory = () => {
    return axios.get('/api/categories/' + props.categoryId)
}

const getCategories = () => {
    return axios.get('/api/categories')
}

const getRecipes = () => {
    return axios.get('/api/categories/' + props.categoryId + '/recipes/')
}

const getCategoriesAndCategoryAndRecipes = async () => {
    const res1 = await getCategories()
    const res2 = await getCategory()
    const res3 = await getRecipes()
    singleCategory.value = res2.data
    recipes.value = res3.data
    categories.value = res1.data
}

// when created (in lifecycel hook)
getCategoriesAndCategoryAndRecipes()

// when category page is changed,
watch(route, () => {
    if (!isNaN(props.categoryId))
    {
        getCategoriesAndCategoryAndRecipes()
    }
})
</script>

<template>
    <div class="left-container">
        <div class="form-box">
            <h4 style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 10px">RECIPE HOUSE</h4>
            <form method="post" v-on:submit.prevent="addCategory">
                <input type="text" v-model="newCategory">
            </form>
        </div>
        <ul class="category_ul">
            <li v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="deleteCategory(category.id)">Delete</button>
                <router-link :to="{name: 'category.show', params: {categoryId: category.id }}">
                    <span>{{ category.title }}</span>
                </router-link>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="right-container">
        <span class="icon">
            <i class="fas fa-utensils fa-lg"></i>
        </span>
        <div>
            <span>{{ singleCategory.title }}</span>
            <form method="post" v-on:submit.prevent="addRecipe">
                <input type="text" v-model="newRecipe">
            </form>
            <ul style="margin-top: 15px;">
                <li v-for="recipe in recipes">
                    <router-link :to="{name: 'recipe.show', params: {recipeId: recipe.id}}">
                        <span>{{ recipe.title }}</span>
                    </router-link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

```
// CategoryHome
<script setup>
// import axios from "axios"
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue"

import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const router = useRouter()

const newCategory = ref('')
let categoryId = ''

async function initial() {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get('/api/max')
        categoryId = res.data.id
        console.log(typeof categoryId) // number
        router.push({name: 'category.show', params: { categoryId: categoryId }})
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('error handling')
    }

}

initial()

</script>

<template>
    <div class="left-container">
        <h4 style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 10px">RECIPE HOUSE</h4>
        <form method="post" v-on:submit.prevent="addCategory">
            <input type="text" v-model="newCategory">
        </form>
    </div>

</template>
```

In CategoryHome, console.log(typeof categoryId) output number.
Are categoryId's data type in CategoryHome and categoryId's data type in props in CategoryShow not matching?

Thank you for your help.

I'm sorry My Englsh is not very good.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of your API response? I want to see the category id from the API response.

Comment: If `CategoryHome` is the parent component of `CategoryShow`, I can't see the code where you are importing `CategoryShow` in `CategoryHome`. Besides, what I can see is you are passing the `category Id` as router param not as prop. Can you provide full code or maybe a code sandbox demo?

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I don't have my development PC now, so I send screenshot later.

Comment: router.push in intial function in CategoryHome moves to CategoryShow.vue.
categoryId is from props.
I commented the route.param line.
sorry for being confusing.

Comment: But where are you passing `categoryId` as props? I can see passing `categoryId` only as a param. Can you please highlight that?

Comment: You are using route params, which will always be a string. See this answer for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49930923

Comment: I still don't know the solution.
first, I added the screenshot in my post.

I completely comfused...

Is my understanding described below right?

categoryId in defineProps comes from router.push' params in categoryHome.vue.

in categoryHome.vue, type of categoryId(variable) is number(please refer to comment in my code).

But router.push cast type from number to String.

So I have got the error.

Is it OK now?

if the above is true, I don't know why the error occurs when reloading in categoryShow.vue.
Please let me know if there are any mistakes.

Comment: I edit router.push params in initial() in CategoryHome.vue.
but This does not resolve the error.